# Keras metrics with TF backend vs tensorflow metrics

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, keras-2

When Keras 2.x removed certain metrics, the changelog said it did so because they were "Batch-based" and therefore not always accurate. What is meant by this? Do the corresponding metrics included in tensorflow suffer from the same drawbacks? For example: precision and recall metrics.

Comment: Could you link to the section of the changelog you're asking about?

Comment: My mistake, I misremembered the changelog. The changelog just says that they were deprecated and therefore removed, other places (such as here:https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794) refer to the fact that they are global properties approximated batch wise, which is why they were removed. What does this mean?

Comment: Might it be something related to this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36250 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take precision for example. The [stateless version which was removed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/a56b1a55182acf061b1eb2e2c86b48193a0e88f7#diff-7b49e1c42728a58a9d08643a79f44cd4L106) was implemented like so:

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):  
    """Precision metric.    
     Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.   
     Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of 
    how many selected items are relevant.   
    """ 
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))  
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))  
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())    
    return precision
```

Which is fine if `y_true` contains all of the labels in the dataset and `y_pred` has the model's predictions corresponding to all of those labels.

The issue is that people often divide their datasets into batches, for example evaluating on 10000 images by running 10 evaluations of 1000 images. This can be necessary to fit memory constraints. In this case you'd get 10 different precision scores with no way to combine them.

Stateful metrics solve this issue by keeping intermediate values in variables which last for the whole evaluation. So in the case of `precision` a stateful metric might have a persistent  counter for `true_positives` and `predicted_positives`. TensorFlow metrics are stateful, e.g. [tf.metrics.precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision).