# What does stateful mean in tensorflow metrics in my case?

Tags: tensorflow

I don't really understand the explanation of a stateful metric here: [Keras metrics with TF backend vs tensorflow metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734955/keras-metrics-with-tf-backend-vs-tensorflow-metrics)

Now, if I split my evaluation data in batches and for each batch I use tf.metrics.precision for the precision, does it mean that the previous variables (counter false positives etc. ) are used for the calculation in the next batch? That would be really bad, since I want the single evaluations for each batch (that is why I do the split!)

If this is the case how can I reset the variables for each batch.

I need the single values from each batch for a mean afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `tf.metrics.Precision` and the like (Recall, etc) store true/false positive is because we do not want to estimate them batch-wise (unlike Accuracy or Loss, etc). The original implementation of Precision in `keras` (noted, not `tf.keras`) did exactly what you described (single evaluations for each batch and then aggregate afterward) but was later removed in version 2.0.0 because this way of computing *global metric* is "more misleading than helpful" (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794).

But you may still do what you want to do, you can subclass `tf.metrics.Metric` and implement the logic of Precision in `update_state` method. The Metric API doc on Tensorflow has an example of custom Metrics. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric

I hope this is helpful!